# error message: exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: activereports

I get the error in the subject after the second time it’s run basically. It happens on the last line, student_count = Convert...

When it runs the first time it shows the proper format of columns and column names and title of the report, etc. What I mean is when I enter this code under the script tab, and then click on the preview tab, it shows the column names, report title, etc. However, when I click back on the script tab or designer tab and then click back to the preview tab, it throws that error at me. Therefore, I said the second run stuff because it seems it’s doing it after the first time.

I now ran a debugger in MS VS 2008 and I get `newline in constant` on the last line:
`student_count = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox("Detail","txtR0_SisNumber4″).Name);`

```
public Section section(string sectionName)
{
    return (Section) rpt.Sections[sectionName];
}
public TextBox textBox(string sectionName, string controlName)
{
    return (TextBox) section(sectionName).Controls[controlName];
}
public Picture picture(string sectionName, string controlName)
{
    return (Picture) section(sectionName).Controls[controlName];
}
public string textBoxTxt(string section, string name)
{
    if( textBox(section, name)!=null){
        return textBox(section, name).Text;
    }
    return "";
}

public void PageHeader_BeforePrint()
{
    try{
        picture("PageHeader","imgOrgLogo").Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(textBoxTxt("PageHeader", "dataOrgLogo"));
    }
    catch { }
}
public void PageFooter_BeforePrint()
{
    textBox("PageFooter","txtPageIndicator").Text = "Page "
        + textBoxTxt("PageFooter","txtPageNum")
        + " of "
        + textBoxTxt("PageFooter","txtPageTotal");
}
public void Detail_BeforePrint()
{
    decimal student_count, student_total;
    string percentage_string;
    student_count = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox("Detail","txtR0_SisNumber4″).Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToDecimal(textBox("Detail","txtR0_SisNumber4″).Name);
```

equals to

```
Convert.ToDecimal("txtR0_SisNumber4″);
```

And this might cause the error. I think that this line should be actually look like

```
Convert.ToDecimal(textBox("Detail","txtR0_SisNumber4″).Value);
```